# Undefined variable: total_user in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I tried to count the amount of data in the manajemen_user table using **num_row()** in codeigniter.

here my table(manajemen_user):

```
id|nama|username|email|password|jabatan
1|Admin|admin|admin@gmail.com|123|Administrator
```

here my controller :

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Statistik extends CI_Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        //load model
        $this->load->model('statistik_model');
        $data = array();
        $data['jumlah_user'] = $this->statistik_model->total_rows();

        //load view
        $this->load->view('backend/index',$data);
    }
}
```

here my model

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Statistik_model extends CI_Model
{
    function total_rows() {
        $query = $this->db->get('manajemen_user');
        return $query->num_rows();
  }
}
```

and here my view :

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
          <?php foreach ($jumlah_user as $total_user):?>
          <!-- small box -->
          <div class="small-box bg-yellow">
            <div class="inner">
              <h3><?php echo $total_user ?></h3>

              <p>Jumlah User</p>
            </div>
            <div class="icon">
              <i class="ion ion-person-add"></i>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="small-box-footer">More info <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
          </div>
          <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>
```

but i have an error like this in my view.

**Message: Undefined variable: jumlah_user**

**Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()**

I do not know where the mistake is. sorry i am new in codeigniter. can anyone help me? Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure you have some records in manajemen_user table? I think you must check that $jumlah_user is_array and then use it in foreach.

Comment: Use $query->result(); to fetch all query results.

Answer (score 0):

Controller

```
function index() {
    //load model
    $this -> load -> model('statistik_model');
    $data = array();
    $data['jumlah_user'] = $this -> statistik_model -> total_rows();

    //load view
    $this -> load -> view('backend/index', $data);
}
```

MOdel

```
class Statistik_model extends CI_Model
{
    function total_rows() {
        $this-> db -> select("count(id) as total_count")->get('manajemen_user')->row()->total_count;
  }
}
```

View

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6">

          <!-- small box -->
          <div class="small-box bg-yellow">
            <div class="inner">
              <h3><?php echo $jumlah_user ?></h3>

              <p>Jumlah User</p>
            </div>
            <div class="icon">
              <i class="ion ion-person-add"></i>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="small-box-footer">More info <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
          </div>

        </div>
```

Comment: You are making a mistake in $jumlah_user variable , As $jumlah_user have number value not the array of results.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use foreach. Just use

```
echo $jumlah_user
```

In Codeigniter, if you passing a database result set that has more than one record, then you need to use foreach to fetch data as row-wise.

```
foreach(return_data->result() as $result){
  echo $result->column_name;
}
```

If there are only one record, you can access it as follows.

```
echo $return_data->row()->column_name
```

If you return a single value from your controller to your view, you can directly access it by variable name.